# Canada Student Visa Application Establishing Country Tie Suggestions

Tags: canada

I am married with one daughter and have parents and some assets in my home country. When crafting my Statement of Purpose (SOP) for a Canadian student visa application, what should I prioritize in terms of demonstrating genuine ties to my home country to convince the visa officer of my intent to return after completing my studies in Canada?

Comment: What reason(s) do *you* consider the most convincing? How long is your proposed study course? Put yourself in the officer’s shoes - you’re already planning to leave your family behind in your home country in order to study, what would *compel* you to return once those studies are complete? Do you have a career plan in your home country mapped out, for example? How does your course in Canada link into that and your studies at home up to now?